# How to add our custom PHP page in the new WordPress block theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress 6.0 new block theme (full site editing themes) there are no PHP pages, only a HTML template and template parts. I installed Astory (full site editing theme). I added my external PHP page by adding as a custom template in the WordPress page. But I am unable to get other header, footer, sidebar blocks and styles.

How can I include a custom PHP code page with theme template style in the new full site editing themes?

```php
    <?php
/**
 * @package astory-child
 */


 /* Template Name: member_register_page */ 
 


  ?>

    
    
    <?php

    get_header();

    ?>
    
    </main>

             
                    
                        <div class="pageheading"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
                        
                        
                        
                            <?php the_content();
                            
            

global $wpdb;

        //$memberhousedet = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_fluentform_entry_details WHERE field_name in ('house_no','house_name','house_ownr') GROUP BY id HAVING count(field_name)=1 ORDER BY submission_id");  -> TRASHED VALUES AVOIDED
        
        $memberhousedet = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_fluentform_entry_details WHERE field_name in ('house_no','house_name','house_ownr') and submission_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `wp_fluentform_submissions` where status='trashed' and form_id=6) GROUP BY id HAVING count(field_name)=1 ORDER BY submission_id");
          foreach($memberhousedet as $housedet){
             //echo '<br/>'; 
             $hstblsbvlidary[]= $housedet -> submission_id;
             
              $housetblid= $housedet -> id;
              $housedetsbmsnval= $housedet -> submission_id;
              $housedetres= $housedet -> field_name;
              $housedetval= $housedet -> field_value ;
            $housedetvals[] = array($housetblid,$housedetsbmsnval,$housedetres, $housedetval);
            //$housedetvals[]= array('id'=>$housetblid,'sbval'=>$housedetsbmsnval,'fieldname'=>$housedetres,'value'=>$housedetval);
            //echo '<br/>';
          }
          $distnctsbvals=array_unique($hstblsbvlidary); 
            //print_r($housedetvals);
            
            $cntoftothusdet=count($housedetvals);
             $cntofdstnctentry=count($distnctsbvals);
             $rstarykeyvals=array_values($distnctsbvals);
             //print_r($rstarykeyvals);
              
             for($i=0;$i<$cntofdstnctentry;$i++){
                                            
                 // $rstarykeyvals[$i];  
                 $cnt=0;
                
                 while($cnt<$cntoftothusdet){
                      
                     if($rstarykeyvals[$i]==$housedetvals[$cnt][1]){
                     //echo '<br/>';
                     //echo $housedetvals[$cnt][1].' , '.$housedetvals[$cnt][2].' , '.$housedetvals[$cnt][3];
                
                    $hsdetcmbndary[$housedetvals[$cnt][1]][$housedetvals[$cnt][2]]=$housedetvals[$cnt][3];
                    
                                        
                 }
                 $cnt++;
                 }
                 //
                 
                 
             }
            // print_r($rstarykeyvals);
            //$hsdetcmbndary[204]['house_no']['house_name'];
            // echo $hsdetcmbndary[204]['house_no'].' - '.$hsdetcmbndary[204]['house_name'];
            
            $ic=0;
            
            while($ic<$cntofdstnctentry){
             
              $housnonnamepasngary[] = $hsdetcmbndary[$rstarykeyvals[$ic]]['house_no'].' - '.$hsdetcmbndary[$rstarykeyvals[$ic]]['house_name'];
              
              if (isset($hsdetcmbndary[$rstarykeyvals[$ic]]['house_ownr'])){
                 
                  $housownernmpsngary[$hsdetcmbndary[$rstarykeyvals[$ic]]['house_no'].' - '.$hsdetcmbndary[$rstarykeyvals[$ic]]['house_name']]=$hsdetcmbndary[$rstarykeyvals[$ic]]['house_ownr'];
              }else{
                     $housownernmpsngary[$hsdetcmbndary[$rstarykeyvals[$ic]]['house_no'].' - '.$hsdetcmbndary[$rstarykeyvals[$ic]]['house_name']]='-';
              }
             
             $ic++; 
            }
            
             //print_r($housownernmpsngary);print_r($housnonnamepasngary);  // -> This array has to be passed to jQ for populate in dropdown   
             
                
            
            
            $encodedpasableary = json_encode($housnonnamepasngary);
            $hsownrjsnary = json_encode($housownernmpsngary);
            
            // echo $hsownrjsnary;
            echo '<div class="wp-block-columns">';
            
            
            //$unq_mem_id=$_POST['unq_id'];  $mem_id=$_POST['mem_id'];
            
            
            echo do_shortcode( '[fluentform id="7"]' );
     
            echo '</div>';
    
         ?>
        
          <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        
        var jsonhsvals = <?php echo $encodedpasableary; ?>;
        var jsnhsownrvals = <?php echo $hsownrjsnary; ?>;
        
        //var housdetvals = $.parseJSON(jsonhsvals.value);
        //JSON.stringify(myobject); 
        console.log(jsonhsvals);
        $cntofhousdetary=jsonhsvals.length;
        for(i=0; i<$cntofhousdetary; i++) {
        $('#ff_7_house_name_select').append("<option value='"+jsonhsvals[i]+"'>"+jsonhsvals[i]+"</option>");   
        
        }
        
        //alert(jsonhsvals.length);
        
        $("#ff_7_housownr").prop('readonly', true);
        
        //var conceptName = $('#aioConceptName :selected').text();
            $('#ff_7_house_name_select').change(function(){
                //alert('dropdown value changed !!!'); alert($(this).val()); 
                     var slctd_housenonam=$(this).val();  
                     $("#ff_7_housownr").val(jsnhsownrvals[slctd_housenonam]);
                    
                    
                    
                         
               });
        });   
        
        
         </script>   

            
   
<?php

 get_footer(); 
?>
```

This is a fluent form registration table with dynamic popup and selection added by PHP and jQuery. I want to add this PHP page into my WordPress theme with the same theme styles.

In the old theme I can add by copying `div` classes from `page.php`, but in the new block theme there is no `page.php` page, so I can’t add the same theme style.

Comment: Please share your custom WordPress page code, Without it, we can't suggest anything.

Answer (score 0):

Found a useful site regarding all information regarding adding php templates in wordpress block themes.

Here the link :

https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/how-to-use-php-templates-in-block-themes/